# How to have python launch multiple processes or programs

Tags: python, multithreading

Here is my issue. I have a program that processes a list of 2,000,000 entries. It's Python so it's slowish. I was wondering if I can have my processing program launch multiple instances of itself or have a 'main' program launch lots of processing programs to work on my list. So far when I play around with Threads the speed is the same as if I were to just launch one instance. Can you help or give advise on how to tackle this? Here is a quasi code for this:

```
my_list = [...3,000,000 entries...]

def processList(start, finish):
    for pos, item in enumerate(my_list):
        if pos < finish and pos >= start:
            process_protocol(item)

def main():
    processList(0,100000)
    processList(100000, 200000)
    processList(200000, 300000)
    etc...
```

The problem is that processList calls from main() will not launch simultaneously; and if I Thread them, it is still slow. So how else can I work on my list in chunks to speed this up? Can I launch instances of this program in multiple terminal windows and have my main() program launch those new terminal windows? Please help.

Comment: have you tried ```multiprocessing``` lib?

Comment: Also you can try `Ray` lib